# Laravel $request->input('var') returns null in Controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

//routes

```
Route::get('/section/{id}', 'Controller@section');
```

//controller

```
public function section(Request $request) {
  $id = $request->input('id');
  dd($id);
}
```

//output

```
null
```

1. there is no problem to retrieve $id, if I try to retrieve inside Route through function($id){}.
2. no other kind of errors shown.

Thank you.

Comment: You can try $request->id directly

Comment: @Web Artisan - your solution worked. Magic...

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a route parameter, there are two ways you can access this variable.

Through a method argument, as some answers already suggested:

```
public function section(Request $request, $id) {
```

Or through the route method of the request:

```
$request->route('id')
```

Comment: Thanks Lucas. Apparently route method works, but not the 1st one (even without $id).

Answer (score 2):

[Route parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-parameters) are actually directly provided to your controller function as an argument.

```
public function section(Request $request, $id) {
    dd($id);
}
```

Comment: adding $id to parameters still returned null.

Comment: What is the url you are visiting to get this result?

Comment: url - section/1

Comment: Does it work when you remove the `Request` argument of the function?

Comment: direct call $request->id worked. Everything else still null.

Answer (score 1):

You've specified `id` as a route parameter.  It's not request input (read from stdin).

You need to add the parameter to your method so it can be passed to the controller method:

```
public function section(Request $request, $id) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the `$id` parameter to the function like:

```
public function section(Request $request, $id) {
  dd($id);
}
```

Then you can use `$id` directly.

Comment: adding $id to parameters still returned null.

Answer (score -1):

Adding `$id` to function to parameters still returned null.

But, Web Artisan suggestion:
direct call `$request->id` worked.

**Note:** No quotes on variable.

Comment: You really shouldn't access route parameters this way from your controller method.  They are passed to the method.  Learn to do it correctly, rather than hacking it together.

Comment: A *working solution* instead of "shouldnt" would be better. Web Artisan provided.

Comment: Good luck in your career with that attitude.   Using a framework usually implies you follow the conventions set for that framework.  You must be doing something wrong if $id passed as a parameter is null.  Instead of learning what you're doing wrong, you're piecing together a problem for someone else to fix later on.

Comment: It's prototyping w new framework. Time is of essence. All I needed was solution, any. Thank you for your contribution. Btw there is nothing wrong w the  question in itself;)